# How can I add javascript to an the email?

Tags: javascript, email, mime-types, mime

Is it possible to have a ajax button inside email?
I want to add a button similar to the buttons inside a google calendar meeting invitation email.

Or is there any alternative option???

Comment: HTML is already horrible enough in emails... now JavaScript? Please no!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don’t count on it.  Most if not all mail clients will refuse to run Javascript within an e-mail.

If you want to include buttons, insert images with different links to a public web page of yours.  Also, do include the button images within the mail message itself (and reference them by [Content-ID](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2111.html)), since many mail clients nowadays even refuse to load remote images.

This is exactly what Google Calendar does.  Of course, Gmail recognizes invitation attachments ([text/calendar](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt)), and so provides its own interface for the yes/no/maybe buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the message martign, But I am looking at only web browsers now... Not clients

Comment: @user279244: Then what do you mean by "an ajax button inside e-mail"?  Are you writing a webmail app that will display e-mails inside a web browser?

Comment: In the end, I want the reader to click on a link, that calls a url, but still does not open a new window. If javascript is not the right approach, is there any alternative?

Comment: @user279244: You still haven’t made clear for what environment you’re writing.  Are you building a webmail app?  If not, what _are_ you building?

Comment: I want to get build a infra for getting the feedback through the email.. Just that, I dont want a new window to be opened....

Comment: @user279244: An e-mail contains static content.  Once you’ve sent the e-mail, you can’t change it.  You can’t run javascript, you can’t include an IFRAME, you can’t replace it by another page inside the same window.  By design, that is not possible, because it’s a huge security hole.  If you want people to enter something, you will have to include a link that opens in their browser, and continue from there.

Comment: Can I use any mime parameter for that... I guess google calender uses that.. Is there a hack around...

Comment: I'm echoing Martijn here: you should just have a link pointing to a URL that could be pre-populated with variables? That's how I collect data via email responses.

Comment: So,if images are referenced by content-ID, they wont open in new window... Am I right?

Comment: @user279244: ?!?  No.  Images _never_ open in a new window.  Only links or Javascript pop-ups open in a new window.  Attached images referenced by content-id will be displayed by most (if not all) mail clients; whereas external images referenced by URL will be blocked by many mail clients and webmail apps, and not be displayed at all.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, it depends on mail client but I would be incredibly suprised if I saw any that allowed scripts as this opens the floodgates for huge security compromise risks.

**Edit**

Your best option would probably be to look at support for iframes, again though, I would be suprised if many mail clients allowed use of this element.

Comment: If not mail clients, do I have an option of seeing it in a web browser?