# Using Java Script in email

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook

I am sending am email from a C# application which has html and  javascript in it.
And when I checked the received mail the graphs which should be appearing after the execution of javascript code are not appearing.

I am using outlook to view the email 
Is there some way to make javascript run in an email on outlook

Comment: I think most email clients filter out JS for security reasons. If you need graphs, embed them as images

Comment: what kind of js code You're executing in email body? if it's animation You can do it with css. but js is filtered because of security concerns.

Comment: most if not all (modern) email clients will refuse to run JavaScript embedded in an email. It's a clear security risk. Did you google this? This question has been asked many times before (on SO and other forums) and the answer is clear...

Comment: Quentin, wouldn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193860/add-javascript-in-the-email be a better duplicate? Because it's asking _if_ it's possible to execute JS in emails, not _how_, and it's not also closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript cannot be used in emails, it's a security issue. Most of the email clients will not execute it and more will take it as an issue and remove it instantaneously.

Instead you should export your graphs as png or jpeg images to integrate them.

Hope it helps.